# Difference between $.getScript() and $.get()

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am trying to understand what are the differences between `$.getScript` function in jQuery and the `$.get`.

According to the documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/
and
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

It gave me the feeling that with the `$.getScript` you can send data to the server (as with the `$.get` function) but you can't get data from the server (which you can with the `$.get` function). But it shows in the documentation of `$.getScript`, some lines below in the first example, that you can get also data with the line `console.log(data); //data returned`.

So what is the differences? Is it that with `$.getScript` you can call only js scripts and with `$.get` you can call whatever file? What are the restrictions / benefits of using one function instead of the other?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Both of these are shortcuts to `ajax` function call.
`jQuery.get` is equivalent to:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

While `jQuery.getScript` is equivalent to:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: "script",
  success: success
});
```

It is easy to see that `jQuery.get` can obtain any response type (script, xml, json, script, or html - by default html), and `getScript` is limited to "script".

In short, `getScript` is used to dynamically execute external JavaScript, and
`get` is general purpose function usually used to receive data according to params
passed. However, it is also possible to pass params in `getScript` (in URL) but that
will be not common, because most scripts are static. Finally callback in `getScript` can be used to execute final statements after our script was executed (for example, use some library function after loading it).

Answer (score 1):

`getScript` is designed to allow you to load a script. When you append a script from within a script, it will load the script asynchronous. If you use `getScript`, you can set a callback function for when the other script has completed running.

`$.get` is a basic ajax request, you can do what you want with it. It's completely up you.