# jQuery Ajax Unexpected token < error on 404 instead of normal ajax error handler function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, error-handling

When using the jQuery Ajax function, when specifying error and success handlers, you would expect invalid files and 404 errors to be caught by the designated error handler function, but for some reason my code does not.

Code:

```
// using jQuery 3.4.1
// this code has been taken from a larger function, but the issue can be replicated by pasting
// the following code into the JS Console.

var scriptPath = 'http://mywebserver.localhost/application/invalid.js';

jQuery.ajax( {
    async: false,
    type: 'GET',
    url: scriptPath,
    crossOrigin: false,
    data: null,
    global: false,
    cache: true,
    success: function() {
        debugger;
        // do some stuff
        onResult();
    },
    error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
        debugger;
        Lib.showNetworkErrorAlert( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown );
    },
    dataType: 'script'
} );
```

This results in:

> Uncaught Error From: ~unknown~
>
> Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' in:
>   http://mywebserver.localhost/........ line: 1

Just to clarify, I have looked at the SO questions out there already, but the ones I found tended to focus on the cause of the error. I know what the error 'Unexpected token < in ...' is, its simply JS trying to parse the target as JS, but instead its given a 404 error html file, so the < from the first tag triggers the error.

What I am trying to find out and understand, is why this error appears instead of the normal error handler that is specified. At the very least I would have thought setting the dataType to script would make it give a slightly better error to realise, hey this is a HTML 404 error file, not a script.

Any help and insight greatly appreciated.

*Update:* Here's the Network tab from Dev Tools showing it is returning a 404.

[image: Dev Tools Network Tab]

Comment: Aside from the issue, if you're trying to load JS dynamically, use `$.getScript()`, not `$.ajax()`

Comment: `error:` only fires when the response includes a status error code, e.g is not a 2xx (eg 200).  In this case, your server is returning a 200 http status code, but with a "404" error file - jquery has no way to tell that the HTML being returned is for a 404 error page, it's just text - your server is configured incorrectly.

Comment: You could always specify `dataType:"string"` to your ajax request and then check it yourself before parsing it yourself.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks I'll check that out.

Comment: @freedomn-m according to my Network tab in Dev Tools, the correct 404 is being returned

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan According to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110898/difference-between-getscript-and-get/8110965, `$.getScript()` is just a shortcut to `$.ajax` with the dataType, which I have, so its still going to be the same function. Any particular reason you suggest using that, seems synonymous.

Comment: It makes the intent clearer, and removes almost all of the redundant properties you're using. It also enables you to asynchronously load the script and execute some other logic which depends on it without having to resort to the terrible practice of using `async: false`. Check the examples in the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/#entry-examples)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan okay, gave it a go, but sadly still ended up with the exact same syntax error rather than the error handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is actually a bug in jQuery - rather than me using it incorrectly - which was [reported back in 2018](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/4250), but the fix was only earmarked for inclusion in jQuery `4.0.0`.

However that might be a while away, so I have now [reported the bug again](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/4655) for inclusion in more current versions, and the admins have since discussed this and decided to include it as a fix in `3.5.0`.

#### Explanation of the bug

Normally, using the `dataType:script` attribute tells jQuery's Ajax function "I'm supplying a script, please execute the JavaScript once it has loaded."

The problem was that regardless of the response status code, the file (or whatever was returned) would be evaluated as JavaScript (even if not JavaScript), which of course is going to cause errors if a 404 error returns a 404 Error HTML page.

The solution to this can be seen on [Github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/4655) (Just so I dont explain it incorrectly here), but in simple terms it should no longer execute scripts for unsuccessful HTTP responses.